# Map "windows" key on keyboard to "ctrl"

Tags: xorg, keyboard

I am on Ubuntu and using a Microsoft keyboard. I want to map my <kbd>Win</kbd> key to a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`xmodmap`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xmodmap.1.html) lets you modify keymaps. Make a file to hold xmodmap commands (`~/.xmodmaprc` is a common choice). The <kbd>Win</kbd> keys are called "Super" in xmodmap (Super_L and Super_R for the left and right ones). By default they're connected to `mod4`, so you want to remove them from that modifier and add them to `control`. Add this to the command file:

```
remove mod4 = Super_L Super_R
add control = Super_L Super_R
```

Tell `xmodmap` to load it with:

```
$ xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc
```

It will only last as long as your X session does, so you'll need to rerun it each time, or put it in something like `~/.xinitrc` so it will be run automatically

Answer (score 12):

```
jinx:819 Z$ grep ctrl /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst | grep win
  altwin:ctrl_win      Control is mapped to Win keys (and the usual Ctrl keys)
  altwin:ctrl_alt_win  Control is mapped to Alt keys, Alt is mapped to Win keys
```

Go into the keyboard settings, click "Options", expand "Alt/Win key behavior", and select "Control is mapped to Win keys".

(Command line version:  `setxkbmap -options altwin:ctrl_win`, then edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and add `XkbOptions "altwin:ctrl_win"` to the keyboard `InputDevice` section.  (If there is already an `XkbOptions` line, then add it to that line, separated by a comma:  `XkbOptions "grp:alt_shift_toggle,altwin:ctrl_win"`.)

Comment: Oh, that's somewhat simpler than my answer. Nice

Comment: /usr/bin/setxkbmap von debian x11-xkb-utils-7.7+2 have the "-option" clause without the "s" as in "-options".

Comment: and debian since long years ago have unified console and x11 keyboard configurations in "/etc/default/keyboard". this file have x11 syntax, and is sourced by xserverrc, while translated for setupcon in an initscript.