# stop xmodmap key mapping repeatedly reverting from unknown cause

Tags: linux, keyboard, xfce, screensaver

I'm using an aluminum Apple keyboard with my Mandriva 2010.2 Linux system. I remap the Apple Command key (<kbd>⌘</kbd>) to <kbd>control</kbd> using the following `.Xmodmap` file:

```
keycode 134 = Control_R
remove mod4 = Multi_key
add Control = Control_L Control_R Multi_key
```

If I allow `xscreensaver` to activate and run for some time, it appears to undo this remapping. I subsequently have to run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` again manually.

Is there any way to avoid this? I'm using XFCE as my desktop environment.

Comment: I've run into this before where things are able to reset any changes made by xmodmap after X starts and revert to the default X layout. VMware used to do this all the time. If I can remember what I did to fix it so that xmodmap wouldn't get over-written I'll get back to you on this.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, although I didn't pin it down to a screen saver, that's got me thinking, but all I know is that after some duration the `xmodmap` settings that I successfully applied automatically on login somehow revert all by themselves. I guess a workaround is to use another method to more permanently affect the bindings but I'd really like to know who is un-setting my xmodmap, or re-applying a keymap in the middle of a session without being asked. What did you discover, @Caleb?

Comment: Also the same question here, although no useful answers at this time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370024/xmodmap-deconfigures-automatically

Comment: I did find a comment here that may help your situation https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=119441 which recommends "put your xmodmap script into the folder /etc/apm/scripts.d, then creating a symbolic link to it in /etc/apm/resume.d". Presumably this ensures the script is re-applied after power management may have interrupted.

Comment: Just another clue in case it helps someone track down the culprit - I've just noticed that although my mappings don't revert due to a screensaver or power management state change, the revert may be associated with the bluetooth keyboard disconnecting on idle, and re-connecting. There may be some keyboard reset operation that gets run.

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago I used a PC keyboard with a Macintosh multi-booting Mac OS 9, Mac OS X and Linux. The windows key generated the same keycode as the Apple Command Key and showed up in linux as 'meta' or something. Try [geekosaur's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9098/map-windows-key-on-keyboard-to-ctrl/9104#9104) for mapping the windows key here.

Even if it is the wrong keycode, something very similar should do for you.

Edit: Example of xorg.conf section to map the Control function to the Windows keys according to geekosaur's instructions.

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver    "keyboard"
    Option    "XkbLayout" "us"
    Option    "XkbOptions" "altwin:ctrl_win"
EndSection
```

Comment: Setting the mapping isn't the problem here, the problem is it is getting UN-set by something else.

Comment: [This post](http://superuser.com/questions/246345/how-can-i-make-my-super-keys-windows-key-behave-more-like-ctrl-alt-shift-in-lin) describes how to make the change permanent when using `xkb`, but it seems that `~/.xkbmap` or `~/.Xkbmap` is not automatically parsed on my system when I start an X11 session.

Comment: @Caleb, the important bit from geekosaur is the 'Section "InputDevices" ... XkbOptions "altwin:ctrl_win" ... EndSection' in /etc/X11/xorg.conf. This avoids the ~/.Xmodmap not loading, rogue window managers, and xscreensaver cannot touch it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply permanently define another layout, or key bindings. Here:

[how to assign another modifier to Alt key for X11?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9635/how-to-assign-another-modifier-to-alt-key-for-x11)