# How can I use GNOME's keyboard settings in Fluxbox?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, window-manager, keyboard-layout, fluxbox

My GNOME keyboard settings do two main things:

- Switch CMD and CTRL (I'm on a Macbook)
- Give me a third level (for special characters)

This is really the only functionality I'm missing in Fluxbox. Any way to activate it without running GNOME?

Answer (score 1):

If, by "third level", you mean using eg. the American Internation keyboard layout, you can set up your system to use it by default.
On Debian (and quit possibly siblings; (X|K)Ubuntu, Mint and so on), you can put the following in `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105" #physical keyboard model
XKBLAYOUT="us" # keyboard layout
XKBVARIANT="altgr-intl" # keyboard layout variant
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,numpad:microsoft" # terminate X on
    # CTRL+ALT+DEL, and use Microsoft style numpad
```

There's probably a lot of other places for keyboard configuration on other flavours of Linux – on Gentoo/Funtoo it's in `/etc/conf.d/keymaps`

Regarding switching the CMD and CTRL keys, I think it's already been answered here: [Map "windows" key on keyboard to "ctrl"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9098/map-windows-key-on-keyboard-to-ctrl).
Keeping in line with the above configuration, just add `altwin:ctrl_win` to the XKBOPTIONS line, like this:

```
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,numpad:microsoft,altwin:ctrl_win"
```